# How to choose something from a string

Tags: python

Hi I am new to python and I want to choose '**150000**' from this string = *"Successful transfer of 150000 XAF to NAME_1 NAME_2 (237651130929) Fees: FCFA 0 at 2023-10-05 12:51:05. transaction Id: 7131651776. Reference: JCE Odza - Implantation 1."* How can I go about it, I have over 3000 similar cases to sort?

Is there a method to get a strings and/or number between the words **of** and **XAF** for what I want is found inbetween this words